# datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

how can I fill datagrid from datatable c# wpf?

Comment: are you sure google didn't help you on this question (if all you want is to bind a datagrid with datatable)? Avoid posting if simple google search or existing SO posts can provide the answer. Anyways, here's the [simple example](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/34103-WPF-Binding-DataTable-WPF-Datagrid.aspx). Just set the ItemsSource of DataGrid to the datatable (either throuh XAML or code).

Comment: thank you .I had founded answeer in google))

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any code yet? If so best post a few snippets, and be specific about the problem's you're encountering.

If you haven't started yet I'd recommend googling/bingin' for such a question. There are plenty of tutorials, for example on codeplex:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx

Good luck!